# iOS Animation Works Unexpectedly in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation

I'm developing app which contains horizontal tab bar and I made it myself.
What happens is that when I press 2nd tab bar the bottom view's width is wrong.
Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Here's a code for this.

```
let bottomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollViewSize.height-3, width: tabBarViewWidth, height: 3))
    bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0x92D2CD)
self.tabBarView.addSubview(bottomView)
...
//tab button click event
...
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.bottomView.frame.origin.x = _sender.superview?.frame.origin.x ?? 0
    })
```

Colud any one please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure you are supposed to call `updateContraints` directly like that. Check out the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints

Comment: It doesn't work even I deleted updateconstraints

Comment: Did you layout this line with AutoLayout? If yes, just change constraints rather than change frames.

Comment: Using constraints work for me. Thanks :)